# Nav menu slider over ListView performs badly

Tags: javascript, ios, css, performance, transition

I have written a JS application with a nav menu that slides into view using a simple CSS transition of the transform property.  It performs well on Desktop browsers and Android.  However, on iPhone5/iPhone6 there is a significant delay both before and after the transition, which I am unable to explain or diagnose further.

Below is some additional background, followed by screenshots, slider CSS, and overhead performance experiments with raw results.  Looking for guidance on other experiments I might try or potential solutions.

**Background:**

- Single Page JS application Uses Cordova/PhoneGap to deploy to mobile
- After launch, ~2000 DOM elements allocated, ~8000 max for all views
- Home view is a ListView with a MapView backside (horizontal flip div)
- ListView is somewhat busy with onclick listeners for each row
- NavMenu is a div with a list of menu items
- NavMenu is initially hidden offscreen transformed 100% to the left
- NavMenu slides from left to right over 50-row ListView
- Use pure CSS transition of the transform into position over ListView
- The 300ms transition can take up to an insidious 3000ms to complete
- Transition is smooth but with a noticeable delay both before and after
- Use transitionend event to declare the transition complete

**Prototype** of the app is available [here](https://dev.sizzlescene.com/sizzlesceneclient-dev/dist/index.html).

**Screen shots** before and after transition...

[image: ListView with NavMenu offscreen to the left]

[image: NavMenu after 300ms transition over ListView of 50 rows]

Here is the slider CSS.  NavMenu slider is initialized with classes "slide-control slide-control-transition open-right"  To achieve the transition, the "open-right" class is removed and then readded to hide the menu again.

```css
/*
 * Base slide control element
 */

.slide-control {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 50;
    background-color: white;
}

/*
 * Transition on platforms that can support it
 */

.slide-control-transition {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 300ms;
        -ms-transition: -ms-transform 300ms;
         -o-transition: -o-transform 300ms;
            transition: transform 300ms;
}

/*
 * Background mask
 */

.use-mask {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

/*
 * Initial state of slide control
 */

.open-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}
```

**Experiments tried:**

Note: Raw performance results show overhead in millis (beyond 300ms animation).

Note: Firefox on MBP running Mac OS X Sierra, iphone5/6 running IOS 10.x.

```
**Baseline**:

  firefox:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 27,  values: 23,26,20,26,33,48,20,22,23,33 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 28,  values: 23,26,30,24,24,30,33,25,33,34 }

  iphone6:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 652,  values: 661,655,650,647,665,643,644,657,653,647 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 656,  values: 669,643,657,692,636,646,654,685,635,646 }

  iphone5:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 2227,  values: 2298,2154,2157,2143,2086,2908,2128,2160,2139,2095 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 2193,  values: 2121,2096,2100,2110,2147,2094,2115,2925,2129,2095 }


**White -> Transparent background:**

  firefox:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 33,  values: 36,34,33,54,49,20,32,31,21,22 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 32,  values: 42,37,36,27,29,27,27,39,24,30 }

  iphone6:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 677,  values: 711,702,677,667,673,672,653,682,666,669 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 670,  values: 687,704,660,659,660,657,668,664,657,681 }

  iphone5:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 2272,  values: 2977,2066,2107,2887,2076,2128,2081,2133,2133,2135 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 2248,  values: 2891,2075,2102,2084,2073,2878,2116,2104,2082,2077 }


**3D -> 2D transforms:**

  firefox:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 27,  values: 40,25,19,31,29,27,22,17,31,25 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 34,  values: 42,39,42,38,32,28,30,31,40,20 }

  iphone6:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 699,  values: 730,704,732,698,688,690,696,704,648,700 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 667,  values: 688,622,658,662,674,676,669,669,683,671 }

  iphone5:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 2190,  values: 2292,2183,2249,2162,2185,2162,2159,2130,2169,2209 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 2135,  values: 2135,2141,2309,2115,2107,2131,2098,2103,2110,2099 }


**Mask with default background:**

  firefox:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 31,  values: 37,34,30,32,28,24,31,30,32,29 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 27,  values: 17,38,22,34,24,29,20,25,30,30 }

  iphone6:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 652,  values: 692,665,653,644,651,644,648,650,641,634 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 643,  values: 619,653,639,639,646,658,641,644,639,648 }

  iphone5:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 2102,  values: 2200,2126,2122,2116,2066,2050,2107,2104,2076,2048 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 2086,  values: 2151,2076,2105,2075,2073,2077,2074,2076,2089,2065 }


**ListView with no gradient background: (small portion visible)**

  firefox:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 261,  values: 271,259,267,262,262,258,259,258,257,258 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 264,  values: 265,271,271,258,261,270,259,262,261,261 }

  iphone6:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 630,  values: 611,627,651,637,630,631,635,630,628,623 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 639,  values: 668,635,640,635,633,643,633,662,632,613 }

  iphone5:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 2097,  values: 2191,2111,2096,2100,2063,2057,2109,2056,2100,2091 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 2081,  values: 2074,2063,2080,2081,2068,2063,2179,2081,2061,2059 }


**Reduce ListView rows to only those visible:**

  firefox:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 24,  values: 19,31,24,22,18,33,30,18,22,18 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 27,  values: 24,29,33,27,18,31,29,21,22,33 }

  iphone6:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 250,  values: 250,261,249,240,259,245,264,237,253,243 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 260,  values: 250,265,251,255,270,269,276,256,249,255 }

  iphone5:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 511,  values: 565,515,508,492,511,496,495,501,512,514 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 517,  values: 522,517,517,515,519,518,515,514,514,515 }


**Reduce ListView rows to 0:**

  firefox:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 32,  values: 63,22,60,24,31,19,26,30,21,28 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 24,  values: 22,22,25,27,22,33,8,28,24,24 }

  iphone6:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 172,  values: 128,169,178,177,167,167,178,195,178,182 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 176,  values: 187,175,173,169,173,179,185,178,172,167 }

  iphone5:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 473,  values: 678,325,573,855,334,310,302,647,362,346 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 353,  values: 530,301,315,322,406,287,302,340,320,406 }


**Reduce ListView rows to 0 and remove gradient background:**

  firefox:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 22,  values: 19,34,30,22,2,19,32,20,22,20 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 25,  values: 3,28,31,33,23,27,25,20,30,25 }

  iphone6:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 183,  values: 133,270,173,205,174,190,169,175,164,176 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 171,  values: 159,171,175,170,182,174,171,170,168,169 }

  iphone5:
        { name: openSlider,   count: 10,  average: 261,  values: 271,259,267,262,262,258,259,258,257,258 }
        { name: closeSlider,  count: 10,  average: 264,  values: 265,271,271,258,261,270,259,262,261,261 }
```

**Summary Question:**

What other experiments might I run to get some good clues?  Paint/Rendering/Layout profiling on mobile is almost impossible.  Unable to get Chrome Dev Tools to work on IOS using latest ios_webkit_debug_proxy/remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter.  Are there other tools I could be using to get some insight?  Many thanks for any help you can provide on this difficult problem that makes the app unusable on 50% of my target devices.

**Additional Clue1:**

The app also has a textarea for user comments.  It takes 10-20 seconds for the soft keyboard to popup after the touch/click.  Definitely something going on!

**Additional Clue2:**

Using UIWebView, the working set size is ~80mb as reported by Xcode.  Swapping in WKWebView reduced it to ~40mb.  However, there is no change in the latency before and after the transition.  This leads me to believe it may be more about rendering work than memory pressure.  The transition element is separately layered using z-index.  However, I'm wondering if GPU management (loading/unloading) is more likely the bottleneck.  I'd love a good reference on best practices for managing the GPU.